# YouTube API`s not retrieving liveChatId from an ended broadcast event

Tags: api, youtube, request, youtube-api, livechat

I'm trying to retrieve all the chat messages I got from a live streaming, which has already ended. But using the request bellow, it does not retrieves any snippet.liveChatId as mentioned in google documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.liveChatId

If I try on upcoming streaming it does work properly.

How do I get the chat messages in this case, if I cannot get the proper liveChatId?

Some values replaced by MY_XPTO

Request:

```
    GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet&id=MY_ID&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

    Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
    Accept: application/json
```

Response:

```
    {
     "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcastListResponse",
     "etag": "MY_ETAG",
     "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 0,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
     },
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcast",
       "etag": "MY_ETAG,
       "id": "MY_ID",
       "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-04-03T21:23:06.000Z",
        "channelId": "MY_CHANNEL_ID",
        "title": "MY_TITLE",
        "description": "MY_DESCRIPTION",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "MYURL",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "MY_URL",
          "width": 320,
          "height": 180
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "MY_URL",
          "width": 480,
          "height": 360
         },
         "standard": {
          "url": "MY_URL",
          "width": 640,
          "height": 480
         },
         "maxres": {
          "url": "MY_URL",
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 720
         }
        },
        "scheduledStartTime": "2020-04-07T20:00:00.000Z",
        "actualStartTime": "2020-04-07T20:01:00.326Z",
        "actualEndTime": "2020-04-07T21:43:52.000Z",
        "isDefaultBroadcast": false
       }
      }
     ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails) states that:

> string (return type)
> The ID of the currently active live chat attached to this video. **This field is filled only if the video is a currently live broadcast that has live chat. Once the broadcast transitions to complete this field will be removed and the live chat closed down.** For persistent broadcasts that live chat id will no longer be tied to this video but rather to the new video being displayed at the persistent page.

Emphasis mine.

This means that YouTube destroys the `liveChatId` after completion (more precisely, ~400 seconds after the stream or premiere ends), so acquiring the `liveChatId` is impossible by *legal* ways. Moreover, even if you manage to get that ID, you will not be able to use that to modify the chat of a previous livestream.

Comment: @Erkin Alp Güney: is that `~400 seconds` officially documented somewhere? As far as I know it's not.

Comment: No. I have found that out experimentally. After that, you get a chat closed error on the UI and status code 403 using the API. Anything you write in the chat during this period after the stream is not replayable either. That grace period is primarily intended to enable stream authors to troubleshoot problems and restore or point viewers to another livestream.

Comment: UPDATE: Chat closed and live event ended errors are now separate.